# JSF2 preRenderView not triggered

Tags: jsf-2

When I try to execute the below scenario the preRenderView event is not getting triggered Could anyone please suggest me how to achieve this?

Trying to navigate from Page A into Page B. (preRenderView event is getting triggered with no issues)
Page B doesn't have any command button and in the preprocess itself using ConfigurableNavigationHandler trying to navigate into Page C.The problem here I'm facing
is Page C is getting invoked but the preRenderEvent is not triggered.

Here follows the code snippet of Page 2.

```
<h:form>
    <f:metadata>
        <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{pageBeanB.preProcess}" />
    </f:metadata>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove `<f:metadata></f:metadata>`, this is not place for that tag. Read [documentation for that tag](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/metadata.html).

> This must be a child of the . This tag must reside within the top level XHTML file for the given viewId, or in a template client, but not in a template.

`f:event` can be used outside of `f:metadata`, so try to use just `f:event` here.

Comment: Hi Partlov, sorry for the delayed response. I tried as you suggested but no hopes.